# How to get users list and their corresponding blog posts from sinaweibo website

Tags: php, api, web-scraping, weibo, sinaweibo

Sina Weibo is a Chinese microblogging website ,I am doing a scraping project which involve getting of blog post count of each users in this website,

url of website: http://blogus.sina.com/gb/hotbloger/#top

In this page you guys can see the list of all users , onclicking each, we will be redirected to corresponding blog page ,I would like to get number of post count(by checking date and time) of each user.

They are providing api to get details
API: http://open.weibo.com/wiki/API%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3/en

But i don't find any api calls to get these specified details. Is there any other way to get the details? or can we do direct scraping of website? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about users with API method [`2/users/show`](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/users/show).

For example, the first link in the page you mention is to:

```
http://redirect.sina.com/blogus/u/blog.sina.com.cn/u/1763875377
```

This is a redirect to the page of user id 1763875377. You can therefore simply invoke `https://api.weibo.com/2/users/show.json?uid=1763875377`, which will return, among other things, the number of posts of this user (`"statuses_count":1583`).

You could also use [`/2/users/counts`](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/users/counts) endpoint to fetch the number of posts of several users at once.

An access token is required to perform these calls authenticated (basically, you will need to register an application with Weibo).